# R: Setting parameters of a function by composing it with another function

Tags: r

Is there a way to make the following code idea work in R without defining f as a function of x and a?

```
f=function(x) a*x
g=function(y){
  a=2
  return(f(y))
}
```

The context is that I am composing several functions and at each stage, the output of some function is potentially a new parameter in the subsequent functions. I want to avoid making the parameters variables of each function because there (1) just too many and (2) some functions need vector inputs which become even messier when adding all parameters as scalar inputs to these functions.

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do exactly what you're asking, but there may be other solutions---like passing around a `list` or `environment` with all the relevant parameters. Or functionals--make an `f_gen` function that generates `f` with the correct value of `a`, then you can use `f_gen(a)(y)` inside `g`. Without more details, it's hard to know if that's any more useful than having `f` take `a` as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With environments it's possible to define `a` in a new environment and call `f`.

```
f <- function(x) a*x
g <- function(y){
  env <- new.env()
  env$a <- 2
  environment(f) <- env
  do.call(f, list(y), envir = env)
}
g(1:5)
#[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

Note that the environment of `f` hasn't changed.

```
environment(f)
#<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me somewhat like a closure, a nice programming construct of a function that returns a function:

```
f <- function(a){
  return(function(x) a*x)
}

g <- f(2)

g(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the code below is for your objective

```
f <- function(...) prod(...)
g <- function(...) f(c(a=2,...))
```

Answer (score 0):

I now ended up using the superassignment operator which worked for my purposes.

```
f=function(x) a*x
g=function(y){
  a<<-2
  return(f(y))
}
```